# Scheduled Execution of application incorporated with NServiceBus

Tags: c#, scheduled-tasks, nservicebus

I want to have an application run once a day and when it starts, it must read all the messages from the queue it subscribes to, do some processing, publish a message and then close. The messages have been sent via NServiceBus, how do you tell when they've all been processed? I can't figure out how to process all the messages in the queue and tell when the queue it is empty.

Comment: Why do you want the application to finish when the queue is empty?

Comment: Will NSB maintain the schedule or will it be some external entity?

Comment: The schedule will be run by a Scheduled Task and will run only once a day, after the close of business. Once the business has closed, the task will run, process all messages in it's queue and then close again.

Comment: Would it be out of the question to have your task just start the service once a day and then stop it after a time period?  I'm really curious as to why you need batch processing, NSB really isn't set up for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like its an architectural question, rather than NSertviceBus specific.

This is how I would solve it with NSB:

I would have my endpoint (subscriber) implement [Quartz .Net](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/)  and schedule a job that will send a command/message indicating the StartOfBusinessDay (every day).

I would have a Saga, start by the StartOfBusinessDay and when the saga is initialized, I would request a TimeOut of T+(hours to end of business day).

This Saga will continually receive messages and aggregate them for processing later.

When your TimeOut occurs, Process all aggregated messages and publish ProcessCompletedEvent to notify any other subscribers that the end of day batch is completed, then MarkSagaCompleted for that day.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The StartOfBusinessDay will be essentially the second after the previous business day has ended to catch any messages that have just missed the cut off. How does the saga map to the messages coming in over the course of the day?

Comment: Yes.. StartOfBusinessDay can be scheduled to fire the second after the timeout.. also, there is no need to map the messages to the Saga, since there will be only ONE Saga active and ready to receive the messages.

Comment: All the examples I've seen have a mapping, can you provide a snippet to demonstrate how you access the current saga in play? Is as simple as not having a HowtoFindSaga section and just access the elements of the 'data' object?

Comment: Yep.. Just don't put any filter expressions in HowToFindSaga and you can debug the process. You should see the messages being handled by the saga as expected.

Comment: Result! What happens if the Timeout message doesn't arrive?

Comment: If your endpoint is Transactional (default) the message will be delivered to the saga to Timeout. However, if no timeout message were to be send. a saga will continue receiving any incoming messages and no processing will occur.